# Is there any stanza in xmpp for admin to add another member as admin

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework, asmack, strophe

I am working on group chat application, is there any stanza in xmpp, so that an admin can add another member as admin. suppose 'a' is owner, 'a' adds 'b' as admin in his group, can 'b' add 'c' as admin. how to achieve this?? is there any stanza??

Answer (score 0):

Room admins can't grant other users the admin affiliation; only owners may grant the admin affiliation. See http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#grantadmin for the protocol needed for owners to assign the admin affiliation.